# Commas and capitals

Tags: commas, quotation-marks

My question is if the word before the quotation marks should have a comma after it, and also, should the word in quotation marks be capitalized. The sentence looks like this:

Together, let's automatically add "Mmm" to end of this speech.

Comment: It doesn't make sense ("Let's **automatically** do X"). // If this is intended as a quote of direct speech (even if not as yet uttered), using _add_ as a quotative verb, then by convention the first letter of the spoken words is capitalised unless there is a rule overriding capitalisation (some words take a mandatory lower-case first letter). But if it is intended as a recommendation to edit a printed speech, capitalisation is chosen to reflect what will actually be written. I suppose even to the extent of an illuminated 'M'.

Answer (score 1):

The rule that says to use a comma before a quote and caps within a quote such as

> And then she said, “Huh.”

only applies to quotes speech, and not to all uses of a quotation mark. In this context I would use no comma and no capitalization. Similarly, if the quoted word were to end the sentience, the period would go outside, not inside, the quotation marks.

For a discussion see [here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/quotation.htm), which uses the example:

> The phrase "lovely, dark and deep" begins to suggest ominous overtones.

Answer (score 0):

Let's all together say "Mhm!" to end this speech!

Since the quoted word (actually it's a complete sentence, if only an interjection) is used as a direct object, then there should be no comma. But as a sentence it should start with a capital letter.

Instead of "automatically" I would write, "Let's all agree..." And you "end a speech" or "put an end to"one.